# Is it possible do sort Jekyll Collection and Jekyll Data in one array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jekyll, liquid

How can I sort this `<ul>` that the 2 `for` Statements are mixed?

I allready tried with javascript and jquery but I only got the error that the `<ul>` is `NULL`.

```
<ul>
  {% assign docs = site.documents | sort: "title" %} 
  {% for document in docs %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ document.url }}">{{ document.title }} - {{ document.url }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %} 
  {% assign dataDocs = site.data.documents | sort: "title" %} 
  {% for document in dataDocs %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{ document.url }}" download="{{ document.path }}">{{ document.title }} - {{ document.url }}</a>
  </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sorting each list rather than one list. You could make it one list before sorting, and render each item differently by giving them an extra front matter identifier (`is_from_data`):

```
<ul>
  {% assign docs = site.documents | concat: site.data.documents | sort: "title" %}

  {% for document in docs %}
    <li>
      {% if document.is_from_data %}
        <a href="{{ document.url }}" download="{{ document.path }}">{{ document.title }} - {{ document.url }}</a>
      {% else %}
        <a href="{{ document.url }}">{{ document.title }} - {{ document.url }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can add `is_from_data: true` to each item's front matter or with Jekyll defaults in your configuration.

---

Older versions of Jekyll might not have the `concat` filter. You can get around this by pushing each element to a new array:

```
{% assign docs = "" | split: "" %}

{% for doc in site.documents %}
  {% assign docs = docs | push: doc %}
{% endfor %}

{% for doc in site.data.documents %}
  {% assign docs = docs | push: doc %}
{% endfor %}
```